# Teamcity: Drop-Down list for Configuration parameters

Tags: plugins, deployment, teamcity, continuous-deployment, teamcity-6

I am using Teamcity for automated deployment process in our application. It's a parametrized build where users will specify the environment, build location etc etc ...

[image]

Now, the thing is, can I get a drop down list to select these parameters from a predefined set?
Is there any way to do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in current (6.5) TeamCity version, but maybe in future release:
[TeamCity 7.0 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Faradi+7.0+EAP+%28build+20334%29+Release+Notes#Faradi7.0EAP%28build20334%29ReleaseNotes-Typesforbuildproperties%28experimental%29)